# PyTorch gather 3D source with 2D index

Tags: python, pytorch

Given a **source** tensor of shape `[B,N,F]` and an index tensor of shape `[B,k]`, where `index[i][j]` is an index to a specific feature inside `source[i][j]` is there a way to extract an output tensor such that:

```
output[i][j] = source[i][j][index[i][j]]
```

`torch.gather` specifies that `index.shape == source.shape`, while here the shape of the source is one dimension bigger.

```
source = [
[[0.1,0.2],[0.2,0.3]],
[[0.4,0.5],[0.6,0.7]],
[[0.7,0.6],[0.8,0.9]]
]
index = [
[1,0],
[0,0],
[1,1]
]

desired_output = [
[0.2,0.2],
[0.4,0.6],
[0.6,0.9]
]
```

Comment: Your formula with the indices does not seem correct. There is a missing bracket, `k` is not defined, and `index` seems to have 3 dimensions whereas you say it should only be 2D.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For future references - The solution is

```
source.gather(2,index.unsqueeze(2)).squeeze(2)
```

Comment: You beat me to it :D Don't forget to accept your answer, I don't think there is much to add to it :)